# Migrate to sql 2017 and add ag's

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017

A client wants to migrate from sql 2008 to sql 2017 and add availability groups. All enterprise. All vm's.

Question: (without using any words starting with Az~ smile) should I set up the ag's first or last?

My instinct is to (side by side) migrate as is. Then once live and stable, separately, add always-on ag's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My instinct is to (side by side) migrate as is. Then once live and stable, separately, add always-on ag's.

That is perfectly reasonable and supported.

However.

Are you sure you really want to perform the cluster creation, configuration and AG provisioning and testing on a live (post-migration) system?

If you do the AGs first, you can perform all that configuration and testing as many times as you want before the migration.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I guess I was falling back on my Replication / log-shipping experience, where I wouldn't dream of replicating / logshiping a database pre-migration.

Comment: Yes, highly advisable to set up the new cluster first, create a test database and play with availability groups a bit as it sounds like you're not too familiar with them.